# getRang(x, x) not returning values added to a sheet using a Google Sheet query ( QUERY() )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the following line of code to get data from a Google Sheet (where sheet is already defined as a Sheet object):

```
sheetContent = sheet.getRange(6,1).getValue();
```

I get no content, despite the fact that there is clearly content there. If I use getRange(5,1), then I DO get content of the row.

Cell (5,1) is populated by an INDEX() sheet function.
Cell (6,1) is populated by INDEX(), copying over from a table that has been populated using QUERY().

I suspect that the QUERY() sheet function has not populated the cells with data by the time I try to access contents using getDataRange() in Google App Scripts.

Does QUERY() save data in Google Spreadsheet?

Am I right in this? Otherwise it could be that the query is taking too long and I'm getting an empty range as a result...

Comment: I made some tests with the importxml() function and I'm globally ok with you. What I made it was a loop with a break() inside to give some time to spreadsheet to calculate change after the getSheet() function. Behavior was not consistent so I don't go ahead on this way.

Comment: Theoretically, you could do a loop every 5 seconds, check if the data was there and then after 3 loops kill the process?

Comment: Yes I made something like but for my file I had to wait multiple importxml() so after spending some times on that with no relevant results I stopped it.